# Optimize where clause using dates

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, optimization

I'm trying to optimize several queries that all use a similar pattern on one of the `WHERE` clauses:

```
AND (DATEADD(DAY
            , ISNULL(a.[due_days], 30) + 30
            , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL))
            ) < GETDATE()
```

The `CalcDate` udf based on the `type` field value makes some comparisons and returns a date. Then adds an amount of days to that date and compares to current date. In order to be able to use an existing index on `due_days` I want to transform the operation to apply all the transformations to `GETDATE()`, let's say I want to make it `sargable`, if possible. Also, if there is some recommendation on what can be done to improve the use of the udf even better.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not so hard to do this transformation. Step by step:

```
DATEADD(DAY
       , ISNULL(a.[due_days], 30) + 30
       , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
       ) < GETDATE()
```

means:

```
[dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
  + (ISNULL(a.[due_days], 30) + 30) DAYS
< GETDATE()
```

then we have to break the `ISNULL()` into 2 cases:

```
    [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
      + (a.[due_days] + 30) DAYS
    < GETDATE()
OR
    a.[due_days] IS NULL
  AND 
    [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
      + (30 + 30) DAYS
    < GETDATE()
```

which can be written as:

```
    (a.[due_days] + 30) DAYS
    < GETDATE() - [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
OR
    a.[due_days] IS NULL
  AND 
    (30 + 30) DAYS
    < GETDATE() - [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
```

so we can use `DATEDIFF()`:

```
    (a.[due_days] + 30) 
    < DATEDIFF( day
              , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
              , GETDATE()
              )
OR
    a.[due_days] IS NULL
  AND 
    (30 + 30) 
    < DATEDIFF( day
              , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
              , GETDATE()
              )
```

and finally:

```
    a.[due_days]  
    < DATEDIFF( day
              , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
              , GETDATE()
              ) - 30
OR
    a.[due_days] IS NULL
  AND 
    30
    < DATEDIFF( day
              , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
              , GETDATE()
              ) - 30
```

---

Corrected, taking care of the time parts:

```
    a.[due_days]  
    < DATEDIFF( day
              , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
              , GETDATE()
              ) - 30
      - CASE WHEN DATEADD( day
                         , DATEDIFF( day
                                   , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
                                   , GETDATE()
                                   )
                         , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
                         ) > GETDATE()
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END
OR
    a.[due_days] IS NULL
  AND 
    30
    < DATEDIFF( day
              , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
              , GETDATE()
              ) - 30
      - CASE WHEN DATEADD( day
                         , DATEDIFF( day
                                   , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
                                   , GETDATE()
                                   )
                         , [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
                         ) > GETDATE()
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END
```

You could simplify it a bit, with the use of `CROSS APPLY`:

```
CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT gdt = GETDATE(),
             calc = [dbo].[CalcDate]([type], date1, date2, date3, date4, NULL)
    ) AS c
CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT diff = x.diff - CASE WHEN DATEADD( day, x.diff, c.calc ) > c.gdt
                                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                             END
      FROM
          ( SELECT diff = DATEDIFF( day, c.calc, c.gdt) - 30
          ) AS x
    ) AS y    
----
    WHERE (  a.[due_days] < y.diff
         OR  a.[due_days] IS NULL  AND  30 < y.diff
          )
```

Comment: Tried same approach, but later when testing didn't got same results when running the query. Will try it right now, thx

Comment: @Yaroslav: Yeah, there is a difference due to how `DATEDIFF` works. I will try to correct it. (A related question: are you sure you want to use `GETDATE()` (the current timestamp) and not the current date in your query?)

Comment: No, I can surely use just current date. As mentioned on the question, while the result remains the same, any recommendation is welcomed

Comment: Does the `dbo.CalcDate()` return dates (without time part) or datetimes?

Comment: Returns datetime. And can not be changed as it is used on several others sp's and udf's. And as I'm still new with database structure and schema don't want to change it to avoid breaking something else in the process

Comment: OK, that explains the difference. So if the returned datetime is 60 days ago, with time `'23:59:00'` and the current time is `'12:00:00'`, using your code, the row will be rejected (because the difference is slightly less than 60 days). But the `DATEDIFF` will see 60 midnights crossed and will show the row. The real question is which of the two behaviours do you want? (so I can adjust the answer.) Please also tag the question with the version of SQL-Server you use.

Comment: Should reject the row, to keep exactly current behavior

Comment: Was doing a long battery of tests, the information returned is vital for sales dept so needed to be sure. So far the version without the CROSS APPLY is working ok and runs an average of 8.3s faster. The CROSS APPLY version will test it now. Checked as correct answer, it answer my question of speeding up things. An amazing job from @ypercube drilling down so far on the query. Thanks